# Spyscope Java RuntimeException No reader function for tag spy/p

Tags: clojure, spyscope

I'm trying out [spyscope](https://github.com/dgrnbrg/spyscope), and following the documented example, I'm getting:

```
user=>  (take 20 (repeat #spy/d (+ 1 2 3)))

RuntimeException No reader function for tag spy/d  clojure.lang.LispReader$CtorReader.readTagged (LispReader.java:1245)
RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
```

My `~/.lein/profile.clj` is:

```
{:user {:dependencies [[spyscope "0.1.6"]]
        :injections [(require 'spyscope.core)
                     (use 'clojure.tools.trace)]

        :plugins [[lein-try "0.4.3"]]
        }
 }
```

My version of Leiningen is:

```
$ lein --version
Leiningen 2.8.1 on Java 1.8.0_212 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

I can't seem to find any answers on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question to make it easier for the next person to looking for the solution.

The answer can be traced to [this issue]: (https://github.com/dgrnbrg/spyscope/issues/8)

> Lein 2 allows users to fire `lein repl` in a non project directory and that's the case

You have to use spyscope within a directory with a `project.clj` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spyscope this way at your profiles.clj

```
; try/catch to workaround an issue where `lein repl` outside a project dir
; will not load reader literal definitions correctly:
(try (require 'spyscope.core)
     (catch RuntimeException e))
```